# How to read images from folder, divide each image and store it in new folder serially

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am taking images from folder('E:\cicila\ME PROJECT\ME 4 SEM\brodatz\IMAGES TAKEN\TRY)  Images are stored as 1. gif  ,  2.gif ,  and so on

I am dividing it . I want to store these images with new name . eg image taken is 1.gif
after diving it into 4 parts, I want to name these new images as 1. gif  ,   2.gif  ,   3.gif   ,  4.gif

Please help me .  I have tried my code but it shows the error :

Error in feb11try (line 25)
Img1(i,j) = NewImage(startr+i, startc+j);

Code is :

```
clc;
close all;
clear all;

srcFiles = dir('E:\cicila\ME PROJECT\ME 4 SEM\brodatz\IMAGES         TAKEN\TRY\*.gif');  % the folder in which ur images exists

%Taking the image from the given URL, it could have been the name of the file with extension if the root folder

n =2; %defining the number of rows
m =2; %defining the number of columns


for c = 1 : length(srcFiles)

   NewImage = 'newimage.gif'; %granting permission to create a file and write in it

rf = floor(512/n); %generating the number of row pixels in the new file
cf = floor(512/m); %generating the number of row pixels in the new file

for v = 1:n
for s = 1:m %nXm files need to be made

startr = (v-1)*rf;
startc = (s-1)*cf;

for i = 1 : rf
for j = 1 : cf

Img1(i,j) = NewImage(startr+i, startc+j);
end
end


imwrite( NewImage,'c.gif');

end
end


end
```

Comment: You never read the image in. Take a look at the imread function.

Comment: OK , LET ME TRY AND SEE ..THANK YOU :)

Comment: I have added it but still it is showing error. Could you please correct the code and give me .Thankyou

Comment: Yes, your error is because it seems that you're treating NewImage as if it contained image data, but it's just a filename, i.e. an array of chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `imread()` to read in the source image rather than treating the filename as an image. Based on what you have, I assume your image is single channel. I also made the assumption that your image is unsigned int. Also, keep in mind there are much faster ways to perform this using indexing.

I made a few changes to your sample that should get the job done under these assumptions. This is untested.

```
clc;
close all;
clear all;

srcFiles = dir('E:\cicila\ME PROJECT\ME 4 SEM\brodatz\IMAGES         TAKEN\TRY\*.gif');

n = 2; %defining the number of rows
m = 2; %defining the number of columns

count = 0;    
for c = 1 : length(srcFiles)
    srcFilename = ['E:\cicila\ME PROJECT\ME 4 SEM\brodatz\IMAGES         TAKEN\TRY\' srcFiles(c).name];
    srcImg = imread(srcFilename); % Read source image
    [~,srcName] = fileparts(srcFilename);

    rf = floor(512/n); %generating the number of row pixels in the new file
    cf = floor(512/m); %generating the number of row pixels in the new file

    % initialize output image
    destImg = uint8(zeros(rf,cf));

    for v = 1:n
    for s = 1:m %nXm files need to be made


        startr = (v-1)*rf;
        startc = (s-1)*cf;

        for i = 1 : rf
        for j = 1 : cf

            destImg(i,j) = srcImg(startr+i, startc+j);

        end
        end

        count = count + 1;                
        imwrite( destImg, sprintf('%d.gif', count) );
    end
    end

end
```

Comment: Ok, I fixed the indexing error and tested the code.

Comment: there are 3 images in folder , and this code is taking the first divided part of each image in folder and displaying it. A total of 12 images are needed, but only the first divided part  of the images are displayed, not the 2nd or 3rd or 4th part of the images.

Comment: I had changed the directory when I was testing the code, the script should now read all the images in the folder named `E:\cicila\ME PROJECT\ME 4 SEM\brodatz\IMAGES         TAKEN\TRY\` and write images into the working directory.

Comment: could you please give me the new code after you have fixed the indexing error

Comment: I already edited my response. If somethings not working then an assumption about your directory or image size/number of channels is probably incorrect.

Comment: yes , it does... :)  I need to use this code to divide 160 images and create new 160x4=640 images,. these new images need to have the name 1.gif , 2.gif,....640.gif. How can I do that.  I need these divided images for my next part of project implementation.

Comment: Ok should be ready now. If its what you need please accept as answered :)